# common sequence across multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I'm trying to create a sequence owned by multiple tables, to have a unique identifier over more tables. The only workaround i can think about right know is using a nextval(blabla_id_seq) when INSERTing, but obviously it wont work when using COPY (or some other situations which i can't think of right now).
So anybody know a solution or  another workaround for this ?   Purpose of question is mostly educational.

Cheers,
Don

LE And can i implement a global primary key for two (or more) table , parent and child? Currently i tried

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS child;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parent;

CREATE TABLE parent (
id serial PRIMARY KEY
, categ varchar(20) NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE child (
else varchar (30) NOT NULL
, id integer -- i have also tried with no id in child table, on;y when using   
--"id serial" does id become primary key
, CONSTRAINT PK__child PRIMARY KEY (id)

) INHERITS (parent);

COPY parent (categ)
FROM 'E:\\1\\_parent.csv'
WITH CSV;

COPY child(categ,altceva)
FROM  'E:\\1\\_child.csv'
WITH CSV;

INSERT INTO child (id,categ,altceva)
--VALUES(nextval('parent_id_seq')+3,'kid7','blabla');
VALUES(5,'kid7','blabla');
```

but i can insert duplicates

Comment: Can't you set the default value of the column to the sequence's nextval?  That's usually how you do this.

Comment: It works...only problem  now is how to enforce the unique constraint across the two tables (i thought a PRIMARY KEY on the parent table solves that but it works ONLY on the parent table).. any elegant solutions to this (meaning no triggers)?

Comment: Why are triggers not considered "elegant"?

Comment: Well i must admit that's just an impression..but i guess that there are situations where using a trigger is the most elegant solution

Comment: Why do you need uniqueness across tables at all?

Answer (score 6):

This question is old and all, but here's a simple answer.

This looks like some sort of inheritance model and the natural solution to that in my mind is to use a common base table. The base table consists at the least of a single serial column. Optionally it may contain fields for attributes that are common for all the objects/nodes in the system.

```
node(serial node_id, timestamp creation_time default now())

book(integer node_id [foreign key => node.node_id], string title, timestamp published_time)
user(integer node_id [foreign key => node.node_id], string name, timestamp joined_time, string display_name)
car (integer node_id [foreign key => node.node_id], string model, timestamp manufactured_time, real miles)
```

When you want to add a new object, or `node` as it were, then you first insert into `node` and then use the returned autogenerated serial `id` to insert further details into the subtyped tables.

This doesn't require any special considerations like transactions, checks, triggers and so on, nor will creation ever fail due to uniqueness errors.

As an extension, you can add a `string type` field to the `node` table and gain the ability to accept any `node_id` and straightforwardly find the corresponding object.